# dashing job undefined map method error

Tags: ruby, dictionary, dashing

I'm using the dashing dashboard to display some data. Part of my code for one of the jobs uses the map! function in ruby:

```
vars = arr.map! { |element| element.gsub(/.{3}$/, '' )}
```

and when I try to run the dashboard using dashing start, I get the following error :

```
scheduler caught exception:
undefined method map! for #<Hash: 0x......>
```

If I run the code on its own as a ruby program, I get the correct result.

Comment: It looks like you expect `arr` to be an Array, but when you receive that error `arr` is a Hash. Can you provide the code that defines `arr`?

Comment: arr = JSON.parse(response.body). when I print arr I see an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the JSON module indicates that the `parse` method will "...convert your string into a hash." See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Parsing+JSON.

Try calling just `map` on your hash instead of calling `map!`:

```
vars = arr.map { |element| element.gsub(/.{3}$/, '' )}
```

The difference is that `map` will return *a new array* with the results of running your block once for every element in the Hash. Also, `map` is defined in the Enumerable module, which is included by Hash, but `map!` is not defined in Enumerable. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map.